# Log UTF-8 characters in ColdFusion

Tags: utf-8, coldfusion

Is it possible to get ColdFusion to log UTF-8 data (eg: Chinese characters) using `<cflog>`?

By default it just logs questions marks instead of the characters.

I know I could open/write/close the log file using the file API, but I'm don't want to over-complicate something as simple as logging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, but you need to tell your entire JVM to process files as UTF-8. You can do this via adding this to your java.args in jvm.config:

```
-Dfile.encoding=utf8
```

[Reference](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/859351).

Answer (score 2):

You may also be able to set `log4j.appender.LOGFILE.encoding=UTF-8` in ColdFusion's `/lib/log4j.properties` file and not affect the whole VM. Although if Adam's solution works, I'd not necessarily change it.

Comment: I'd lean the other way, @barnyr: just changing the log settings would be better than changing the whole JVM. IE: your answer - if it works - is better than mine. And worth investigating.

Comment: I'm not having any luck with this approach. My log files are back to showing question marks. Have you had success with this yourself?

Comment: I've not tried this myself, but from other Java-related threads on SO, it looked like this would work. I think it was worth a go but if it's not working, I'd go back to Adam's approach. Just remember that you've made the change if you see any odd errors in CF in the future and consider briefly undoing the change if you see errors.

Comment: I hear you. I expect there will indeed be other consequences from such a change. Thanks for your time!